# PHP destruct - не почему не работает

Tags: php

Есть класс

```
class X
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->array = array();
        }
        function __destruct()
        {
            return $this->array;
        }
        function getAllData()
        {
            array_push($this->array, 'no_enter_data');
        }
    }
```

Вызываю функицю

```
$result = new X;
print_r($result->getAllData());
```

Но возвращает пустой массив почему не могу понять.

Comment: `return` в методе `getAllData` не забыли?

Comment: А разве не будет запускаться дестракт после выполнения ГетАллДата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите увидеть результат тут - `print_r($result->getAllData());` то нужно возвращать результат:

```
function getAllData()
        {
            array_push($this->array, 'no_enter_data');
            return $this->array;
        }
```

Если вы хотите получать при `__destruct`, то тут немного по другому.

Деструктор вызывается, но результат его работы не выводится, поэтому `return` бессмыслен. Надо тогда так:

```
class X {
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->array = array();
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        print_r($this->array);
    }
    function getAllData()
    {
        array_push($this->array, 'no_enter_data');
    }
}
$result = new X;
$result->getAllData();
```

P.S. стоит учитывать что деструктор вызывается при разрушении класса. Обычно - в конце работы **всего** скрипта.